# Number of sites are refusing to connect on Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, internet-connection

Out of nowhere, a number of sites on Google Chrome are simply refusing to connect. Going through Google for a while, I've tried doing the following:

- Reinstalling Chrome
- Clearing data and cache multiple times
- flushing and resetting DNS using `ipconfig`

It should be mentioned that the same sites are opening on Chrome when using VPN. Also, they're opening fine in Firefox and Edge with no VPN.

Nothing seems to be working. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What error message?

Comment: @DavidPostill ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED